# Probability of any one horse winning=?

Tags: probability

I changed a question i found in my textbook a little bit and ran into a problem :-
Say there are three horses A,B and C and the probabilities of any one of them winning the race are $\frac{1}{2}$, $\frac{1}{3}$ and  $\frac{1}{4}$, respectively. Find the probability that any one of them wins the race.
Here, we need to use the formula :- $$P(A\cup B\cup C) = P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - P(A\cap B)-P(C \cap B)-P(A \cap C) + P(A \cap B \cap C)$$
But only one of them can win the game so, A$\cap$ B = $\phi$ and A$\cap$ B$\cap$ C = $\phi$. But then the probability exceeds 1. Where am i wrong ? (Note: In the textbook, the probabilities were 1/3,1/4 and 1/5 respectively, and the same method has been used to solve the problem.)

Comment: It is just not possible for the probabilities to be $\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}$, and $\frac{1}{4}$, exactly because they add up to more than $1$.

Comment: If no ties are allowed and one horse has to win,  the three probabilities must add up to $1$. So the book figures are also suspect.

Comment: @trueblueanil: At least in the book's case, the figures leave open the possibility of none of the three horses winning the race (e.g., there are other horses, it is possible for all three horses to not finish, etc.).

Comment: The original textbook numbers were fine if there's another, 4th horse or even group or horses, which might win., distinct from A, B, C.  Or some other condition- no horse wins due to race cancellation, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Could be, if the ensemble is a set of races, where they never run against eachother. By common betting shop sense, the probabilities may be renormed to unity to be used as a first a priori guess until enough data are available from races of all pairs and all three of them togehter, necessary to update the experimental single win probabilities.

Comment: My tutor said the same, but i am not able to understand as to why this is true ?

Comment: In statistical physics and finance mathematics its common, to work with unnormed probabilities {p_k}. All results of measurements are defined to be $$ E(X) = \frac{\sum x_k p_k}{\sum p_k}$$.  Especially for exponential distributions (themodynamics) the expectations can be calulated by logarithmic derivatives of $$Z=\sum p_k$$. For your example see the ancient mathematical paradox of the testament, that divides the old arab fathers of 17 camels  https://mathoverflow.net/question